# installing Oracle 11g on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to install Oracle on my computer. I have Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5. Can you please give me the exact instructions and the steps to follow to install it.

Thank you.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you!

Comment: If you go the VirtualBox route, then depending on what you're planning to do you might find [these pre-built VM images](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) useful - easier than installing Linux yourself and unless you plan to actively do DBA stuff, easier than installing Oracle too...

Comment: I just installed VirtualBox and the link that you sent is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!